# Life expectancy of usb stick when datalogging

Tags: c, file, stream, usb, plc

I know that on average a flashdrive has a life expectancy of roughly 100,000 write cycles. This raises a question for me

I have written a program where I write some values to a csv file on a usb stick every 6 seconds. Every day a new file is created. The machine is a Sigmatek PLC programmed in structure text (similar to pascal) with C library for file handling. The code looks something like file fopen (opens todays file), write some values to the stream along with a timestamp, then file fclose (close the file).

I heard someone say this could mean my usb stick will not last a long time since I'm opening and closing the file every 6 seconds. He suggested I opened the file, write values every 6 seconds as usual, and then close after 10 or 20 minutes, this way the usb stick would last a lot longer. His reasoning being that the usb stick will only be written to at the moment you would actually close the file with Fclose. Can someone confirm this?

Or will this perhaps not become a problem at all even if im opening and closing every 6 seconds, since the usb stick has 16gb of memory, and will only run out of memory after a looooong time (1 file is 500kb max, one file created evey day) , therefore I'm only writing and not writing and erasing from memory? Is the 100,000 write cycles lifetime based on purely writing or writing, erasing and re-writing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, regarding a `fclose()` every 10-20 minutes.  This depends on the buffering mode (for C, see `setvbuf`).  In buffered mode, what you were told is correct - any buffered data is written at the time of a `fclose()`.  However, there is an increased risk of losing data (e.g. sudden power loss means unwritten buffer is lost).

We've also made embedded systems using writable flash (not USB).  100,000 write cycles is hugely variable.  It means "P/E" (program-erase) cycles.  If you're only appending data, then at the rate you cite, I would not bother too much about it.  If you're doing other things like erasing/compressing log files which could result in the same storage location being written multiple times, then you need to think more about it.  You'd also need to look at what is being done by the OS - for example, any type of auto-defrag should preferably not be enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I will leave it at open / close every 6 seconds, since I am indeed only appending to an existing file, or creating a new file at the beginning of a new day. In this case I normally never erase and rewrite to the flash drive